# Unexpected behavior of util.inspect

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

util.inspect seems to behave differently in a node repl and a custom repl

```
$ node
> require("util").inspect([])
'[]'
>
```

output in custom repl

```
$ node repl.js
> require("util").inspect([])
'Array []'
>
```

content of repl.js

```
var repl = require('repl');
repl.start({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't duplicate this with the current master branch. I get `'[]'` in both cases.

My guess is that this was fixed in [089d68861](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/089d6886178864b56fdd5dc2bcfc8f207aa4326c).

Comment: I just upgraded to v4.2.1 and the `Array ` prefix disappeared, but there is still a `Object ` prefix when inspecting `{}`.

Comment: @Feng I've submitted a PR to fix the `Object ` prefix issue [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/3385).